# Java RMI ClassCastException

Tags: java, ftp, network-programming, client-server, rmi

I get the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to ServerInterface
```

when (second line causing the issue)

```
Registry myreg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(hostname, portnumber);
interOne = (ServerInterface) myreg.lookup(ServerOne);
```

interOne has been declared already as

```
private static ServerInterface interOne;
```

and it is just one of the three instances of the server interface; there are three in total. The server interface is as follows:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface ServerInterface extends Remote {

    void uploadFileToServer(byte[] mybyte, String serverpath, int length) throws RemoteException;

    byte[] downloadFileFromServer(String servername) throws RemoteException;

    String[] listFiles() throws RemoteException;

    boolean removeDirectoryOrFile(String serverpath) throws RemoteException;

    int directorySize(File directory);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The remote interface used by the client must be identical in all respects *including package* to the remote interface exported by the remote object.

Two interfaces in two different packages are different, regardless of what other similarities they may share, including their name.